# Ubuntu 18.04.4, Logrotate is not working, syslog is generating files logs over 50GB

Tags: 18.04, gnome, syslog

I have a Helios Acer Predator 300 computer (Predator-G3-572) and recently did a hardware update, installing a 1Tb SSD. This greatly improved performance, allowing for more machine efficiency, both for work since I am a developer and for games.

However, I started to notice a problem, now the system does not seem to work properly anymore, recording a syslog file of exorbitant sizes (the last file I deleted, was about 50GB).

**UPDATE:**

I believe the problem may be the logrotate. In analysis, I went to check if the logrotate program was working properly. At first all settings are normal, but the syslog file is now larger than 1 MB, while it should rotate with 100 KB.

Example, one-day log:

```
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: message repeated 4 times: [ Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon]
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7efd8c10c4f0]#012kind:                desktop#012state:               available#012quirk:               provenance#012id:                  calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop#012unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-bionic-universe/desktop/calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop/*#012scope:               system#012bundle-kind:         package#012kudos:               has-screenshots#012kudo-percentage:     20#012name:                calibre - E-book Viewer#012pixbuf:              0x7efd842e3400#012icon-kind:           cached#012icon-pixbuf:         0x7efd842e3400#012icon-name:           calibre_calibre-viewer.png#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe#012version:             3.21.0+dfsg-1build1#012summary:             Leia e-books em mais de uma dúzia de diferentes formatos#012description:         Tem um modo de tela cheia para distração de leitura livre e pode exibir o texto com várias colunas por tela.#012screenshot-00:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop/025CBAE41D4395E07AFC2D52AA0542F9/screenshots/image-1_224x126.png [<none>]#012screenshot-01:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop/025CBAE41D4395E07AFC2D52AA0542F9/screenshots/image-2_224x126.png [<none>]#012source-00:           calibre#012source-id-00:        calibre;3.21.0+dfsg-1build1;all;ubuntu-bionic-universe#012url{homepage}:       https://calibre-ebook.com#012license:             GPL-3.0#012license-is-free:     yes#012management-plugin:   packagekit#012origin:              ubuntu-bionic-universe#012origin-appstream:    ubuntu-bionic-universe#012rating:              77#012review-rating:       [0:0]#012review-rating:       [1:2]#012review-rating:       [2:2]#012review-rating:       [3:1]#012review-rating:       [4:2]#012review-rating:       [5:11]#012reviews:             0#012provides:            0#012install-date:        1#012size-installed:      unknowable#012size-download:       24,7 MB#012category:            Graphics#012category:            Viewer#012{GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream#012{appstream::source-file}: /usr/share/applications/calibre-ebook-viewer.desktop
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7efd8c10c750]#012kind:                desktop#012state:               available#012quirk:               provenance#012id:                  calibre-ebook-edit.desktop#012unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-bionic-universe/desktop/calibre-ebook-edit.desktop/*#012scope:               system#012bundle-kind:         package#012kudos:               has-screenshots#012kudo-percentage:     20#012name:                calibre - E-book Editor#012pixbuf:              0x7efd84163640#012icon-kind:           cached#012icon-pixbuf:         0x7efd84163640#012icon-name:           calibre_calibre-ebook-edit.png#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe#012version:             3.21.0+dfsg-1build1#012summary:             Edita textos e modelos em e-books#012description:         O editor de e-book do calibre permite que você edite o texto e os estilos dentro do livro com uma visualização em tempo real de suas alterações.#012#012Pode editar livros, nos formatos EPUB e AZW3 (kindle). Ele inclui várias ferramentas úteis para a verificação de erros do livro, edição do Índice, realizando limpezas automáticas, etc.#012screenshot-00:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-ebook-edit.desktop/E388AC11B2307F63436A12852646E94F/screenshots/image-1_224x126.png [<none>]#012screenshot-01:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-ebook-edit.desktop/E388AC11B2307F63436A12852646E94F/screenshots/image-2_224x126.png [<none>]#012screenshot-02:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-ebook-edit.desktop/E388AC11B2307F63436A12852646E94F/screenshots/image-3_224x145.png [<none>]#012source-00:           calibre#012source-id-00:        calibre;3.21.0+dfsg-1build1;all;ubuntu-bionic-universe#012url{homepage}:       https://calibre-ebook.com#012license:             GPL-3.0#012license-is-free:     yes#012management-plugin:   packagekit#012origin:              ubuntu-bionic-universe#012origin-appstream:    ubuntu-bionic-universe#012reviews:             0#012provides:            0#012install-date:        1#012size-installed:      unknowable#012size-download:       24,7 MB#012category:            Office#012{GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream#012{appstream::source-file}: /usr/share/applications/calibre-ebook-edit.desktop
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7efd8c10c9b0]#012kind:                desktop#012state:               available#012quirk:               provenance#012id:                  calibre-gui.desktop#012unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-bionic-universe/desktop/calibre-gui.desktop/*#012scope:               system#012bundle-kind:         package#012kudos:               has-screenshots|perfect-screenshots#012kudo-percentage:     40#012name:                calibre#012pixbuf:              0x7efd84263300#012icon-kind:           cached#012icon-pixbuf:         0x7efd84263300#012icon-name:           calibre_calibre-gui.png#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe#012version:             3.21.0+dfsg-1build1#012summary:             A solução unificada para tudo o que você precisa em eBooks.#012description:         O calibre é a solução de uma parada a todas as suas necessidades de e-book.#012screenshot-00:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-gui.desktop/41C544EA787D6D3FEAB0824550BF86DF/screenshots/image-1_224x126.png [<none>]#012screenshot-01:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-gui.desktop/41C544EA787D6D3FEAB0824550BF86DF/screenshots/image-2_224x126.png [<none>]#012screenshot-02:       http://appstream.ubuntu.com/media/bionic/c/ca/calibre-gui.desktop/41C544EA787D6D3FEAB0824550BF86DF/screenshots/image-3_224x126.png [<none>]#012source-00:           calibre#012source-id-00:        calibre;3.21.0+dfsg-1build1;all;ubuntu-bionic-universe#012url{homepage}:       https://calibre-ebook.com#012license:             GPL-3.0#012license-is-free:     yes#012management-plugin:   packagekit#012origin:              ubuntu-bionic-universe#012origin-appstream:    ubuntu-bionic-universe#012rating:              89#012review-rating:       [0:0]#012review-rating:       [1:10]#012review-rating:       [2:4]#012review-rating:       [3:5]#012review-rating:       [4:11]#012review-rating:       [5:114]#012reviews:             0#012provides:            0#012install-date:        1#012size-installed:      unknowable#012size-download:       24,7 MB#012category:            Office#012{GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream#012{appstream::source-file}: /usr/share/applications/calibre-gui.desktop
Mar 30 06:24:43 Predator-G3-572 gnome-software[4224]: ignoring non-installed app GsApp: [0x7efd8c10cc10]#012kind:                desktop#012state:               available#012quirk:               provenance#012id:                  calibre-lrfviewer.desktop#012unique-id:           system/package/ubuntu-bionic-universe/desktop/calibre-lrfviewer.desktop/*#012scope:               system#012bundle-kind:         package#012kudo-percentage:     0#012name:                LRF Viewer#012pixbuf:              0x7efd84263120#012icon-kind:           cached#012icon-pixbuf:         0x7efd84263120#012icon-name:           calibre_calibre-viewer.png#012icon-prefix:         /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe#012version:             3.21.0+dfsg-1build1#012summary:             Viewer for LRF files (SONY ebook format files)#012description:         Calibre foi pensado para ser uma solução completa de biblioteca eletrônica. Ele inclui um gerenciador de biblioteca, conversor de formatos, conversor de feeds de notícias em e-book assim como recursos de sincronização de leitores de e-book.#012#012Calibre é principalmente um programa catalogador de e-books. Ele gerencia sua coleção de e-books. Ele foi desenhado ao redor do conceito de livro lógico, isto é, uma única entrada no banco de dados pode corresponder a e-books em vários formatos. Ele também dá suporte a conversão de dúzias de diferentes formatos de e-books para LRF e EPUB. Uma interface gráfica para o software de conversão pode ser facilmente acessada simplesmente clicando no botão "Converter e-books".#012#012Os formatos de entrada para os quais há suporte são: MOBI, LIT, PRC, EPUB, ODT, HTML, CBR, CBZ, RTF, TXT, PDF e LRS.#012#012Calibre possui um desenho modular de driver de dispositivo que torna fácil adicionar suporte para diferentes dispositivos de leitura eletrônica. No momento, ele possui suporte para SONY PRS 500/505/700 e iPhone (com o software "stanza" de leitura). A sincronização dá suporte à atualização de metadados no dispositivo a partir de metadados na biblioteca e à criação de coleções no dispositivo baseada em etiquetas definidas na visualização da biblioteca. Se um livro possui mais de um formato disponível, o calibre escolhe automaticamente o melhor formato quando for enviá-lo para o dispositivo.#012#012O calibre pode automaticamente obter notícias de vários sites web e feeds RSS, formatar as notícias em um e-book e carregá-lo em um dispositivo conectado. Há suporte para geração de e-books LRF/EPUB. Os e-books incluem as versões *completas* dos artigos, não apenas os sumários.#012#012O calibre também possui um visualizador embutido de e-book que pode exibir todos os principais formatos de e-book.#012source-00:           calibre#012source-id-00:        calibre;3.21.0+dfsg-1build1;all;ubuntu-bionic-universe#012url{homepage}:       http://calibre-ebook.com#012license:             LicenseRef-free=https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing#012license-is-free:     yes#012management-plugin:   packagekit#012origin:              ubuntu-bionic-universe#012origin-appstream:    ubuntu-bionic-universe#012reviews:             0#012provides:            0#012install-date:        1#012size-installed:      unknowable#012size-download:       24,7 MB#012category:            Graphics#012category:            Viewer#012{GnomeSoftware::Creator}: appstream#012{appstream::source-file}: /usr/share/applications/calibre-lrfviewer.desktop
Mar 30 06:25:01 Predator-G3-572 CRON[4412]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Mar 30 06:25:14 Predator-G3-572 gnome-shell[3467]: Ignoring excess values in shadow definition
Mar 30 06:25:14 Predator-G3-572 gnome-shell[3467]: message repeated 14 times: [ Ignoring excess values in shadow definition]
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3814] policy: auto-activating connection 'WHO?'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3843] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'WHO?' (b5dd87fe-9e0b-4e05-8389-a3b8aa30fa68)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3849] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3852] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3865] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3873] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'WHO?' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3873] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3876] sup-iface[0x55ce6244ca40,wlp2s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3965] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3976] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3986] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'WHO?' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3987] Config: added 'ssid' value 'WHO?'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3988] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3988] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3988] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3988] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.3988] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 (SSID='WHO?' freq=2457 MHz)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.105965] wlp2s0: authenticate with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 (SSID='WHO?' freq=2457 MHz)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.4204] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.108998] wlp2s0: send auth to 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 (try 1/3)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.111241] wlp2s0: authenticated
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.112780] wlp2s0: associate with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 (try 1/3)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.4258] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: Associated with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.116770] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=1)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.118801] wlp2s0: associated
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.4337] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.8778] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 70:8b:cd:e8:9b:70 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 wpa_supplicant[1055]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-48 noise=9999 txrate=1000
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  163.585109] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.8997] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.8997] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'WHO?'.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9000] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9065] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9096] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): dhclient started with pid 4437
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::cfaf:67ae:3811:d91c.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: Registering new address record for fe80::cfaf:67ae:3811:d91c on wlp2s0.*.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 dhclient[4437]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.50.42 on wlp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x56e191c7)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 dhclient[4437]: DHCPACK of 192.168.50.42 from 192.168.50.1
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9699] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   address 192.168.50.42
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9699] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9699] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.50.1
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9699] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9700] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   hostname 'Predator-G3-572'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9700] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '192.168.50.1'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9700] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.50.42.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: New relevant interface wlp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 avahi-daemon[1048]: Registering new address record for 192.168.50.42 on wlp2s0.IPv4.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 dhclient[4437]: bound to 192.168.50.42 -- renewal in 41928 seconds.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9729] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9734] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9736] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9737] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 whoopsie[1863]: [06:25:16] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9767] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9767] policy: set 'WHO?' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560316.9776] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 dbus-daemon[1027]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1073 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 gsd-sharing[3647]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 gsd-sharing[3647]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 gsd-sharing[3647]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 gsd-sharing[3647]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service not loaded.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 dbus-daemon[1027]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Mar 30 06:25:16 Predator-G3-572 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Mar 30 06:25:17 Predator-G3-572 systemd-resolved[961]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 30 06:25:17 Predator-G3-572 systemd-resolved[961]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Mar 30 06:25:17 Predator-G3-572 PackageKit: get-updates transaction /1700_abddabbc from uid 1000 finished with success after 518ms
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 NetworkManager[1073]: <info>  [1585560323.0901] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 whoopsie[1863]: [06:25:23] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 whoopsie[1863]: [06:25:23] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
Mar 30 06:25:23 Predator-G3-572 whoopsie[1863]: [06:25:23] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6
Mar 30 06:25:24 Predator-G3-572 whoopsie[1863]: [06:25:24] online
Mar 30 06:25:29 Predator-G3-572 gnome-shell[3467]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/notificationDaemon.js 121]: reference to undefined property "image-path"
Mar 30 06:25:40 Predator-G3-572 systemd-timesyncd[959]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Mar 30 06:26:08 Predator-G3-572 dbus-daemon[3317]: [session uid=1000 pid=3317] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.81' (uid=1000 pid=4750 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Mar 30 06:26:08 Predator-G3-572 systemd[3247]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Mar 30 06:26:08 Predator-G3-572 dbus-daemon[3317]: [session uid=1000 pid=3317] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Mar 30 06:26:08 Predator-G3-572 systemd[3247]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166130] mce: CPU0: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166131] mce: CPU4: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166132] mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166134] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166134] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166136] mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166137] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166137] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166140] mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.166150] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167145] mce: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167145] mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167147] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167147] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167148] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167149] mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167150] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167150] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167151] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 kernel: [  270.167152] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5102:1:0330/062703.901587:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Mar 30 06:27:03 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5102:1:0330/062703.902084:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Mar 30 06:27:08 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5268:1:0330/062708.525706:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Mar 30 06:27:08 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5268:1:0330/062708.526372:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Mar 30 06:27:48 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5501:1:0330/062748.564131:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
Mar 30 06:27:48 Predator-G3-572 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[3467]: [5501:1:0330/062748.564628:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
```

**Config Logrotate:**

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
```

**Config to logrotate rsyslog:**

```
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
        size +100k
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
        size +100k
}
```

Comment: Please look at the contents of the `/var/log/syslog` file and edit your question to include examples of whatever message(s) are making it so big. You need to identify and fix the underlying issue, not just manage the file size.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the `terminal` output of `tail -n30 /var/log/syslog`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, I just ran tests with Stacer and lost data from all logs. I am hoping to record the information for at least 1 day, to insert in the post.

Comment: @DougSmythies, thank you very much for the advice, but even analyzing the file I couldn't identify what the error would be. Since the last file had about 50GB I didn't know which title to put for the question.

Comment: @heynnema, I just updated the question, believing that the error may be due to the logrotate.

Comment: @DougSmythies, I just updated the question, believing that the error may be due to the logrotate.

Comment: @vic.py logrotate is not your problem. Review `/var/log/syslog*` more closely, and look for lots of repeating similar errors. In the snippet you uploaded, there was a lot of NetworkManager activity, and CPU's overheating, etc, but there wasn't enough of the log for me to definitively same what's wrong. Post more syslog on paste.ubuntu.com if you wish.

Comment: @heynnema, thank you very much for the suggestion, I just inserted the log generated from yesterday, starting with what was generated today. I will analyze too and try to find the passages in repetition. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/47tH2FpBHp/

Comment: @vic.py Please see my partial answer. Edit your question with the output that I requested. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL your GNOME extensions.

Comment: @vic.py Status please...

Comment: @vic.py Status please...

Comment: @vic.py Status please...

Comment: @vic.py Status please... 4th request...

Answer (score 1):

In reviewing your `syslog`, I didn't have to go to far to find a number of issues. I'll document some of them in the form of this answer, as there's too much to place into comments.

**Note**: Place all output as an edit to your question, not into comments, please.

- **CPUs overheating**
  mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 6796)

  - MCE is machine check error. Generally not a good thing to see. Is it very dirty/dusty?
  - Have you overclocked the CPU/RAM in this computer?
- **GNOME Shell crash**

  - You have one, or more, GNOME Shell extensions crashing... and I see TopIcons as a candidate
  - show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
  - show me `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`
- **drawnio app**

  - generating a lot of syslog output
  - indicates there's an update available
  - snap app?
  - may be responsible for the font issue
- **font issue**

  - possible snap app problem?
  - show me `snap list`
  - have you installed any fonts, or font-related apps?

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Stacer from the Ubuntu Sotware Center.

[image]

The system automatically generates many sys log files but some general housekeeping is always a good thing. The sys log files can be useful in other circumstances.

Select the option System Cleaner regularly to keep things trim and tight.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, I did the tests and noticed that Stacer literally clears all logs. However I do not believe this is the way, because if the system is in error I will not be able to identify it since all the logs have been deleted.

Comment: Just uncheck the logs you want to keep...

Comment: @vic.py  This is the kind of tool that I don't recommend... for exactly that reason. We lost some very important data.

Comment: This is the kind of tool that I don't recommend... for exactly that reason. The user lost some very important data.